# Ubuntu img file with hadoop installed in?

Tags: image, ubuntu, hadoop

Are there any hadoop in ubuntu  img files avalible？ I mean a ubuntu system which has hadoop configured  in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a distribution install, Cloudera has a painless installation process for Ubuntu using Cloudera Manager.  Though it only officially supports 12.04, it should also install on 13.x

You can download it here:  [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads.html)

```
Cloudera Manager supports the following operating systems:

    Red Hat-compatible systems
        Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS 5.7, 64-bit
        Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS 6.4, 64-bit
        Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.4, 64-bit
    SLES systems - SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11, 64-bit. Service Pack 3 or later is required. Also, the SUSE Linux Enterprise Software Development Kit 11 SP1 is required on cluster hosts running the Cloudera Manager Agents (not required on the Cloudera Manager Server host); you can download the SDK here.
    Debian systems - Debian 7.0, 6.0 (deprecated), 64-bit
    Ubuntu systems - Ubuntu 12.04, 10.04 (deprecated), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are neither no "official" ubuntu packages for hadoop nor customized ditributions,  but there is a PPA you could use. See https://launchpad.net/~hadoop-ubuntu/+archive/stable for instructions. So at least you can install "semioffical" packages (including updates).